# Ajax sending empty list via POST request Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, ajax, request

I am sending array of user's answers in my test app and i'm getting two arrays (one of them filled in correctly , but another is empty). Also in console i noticed that i'm getting to requests (POST and GET). How should i send the array via ajax POST so that been sended only one time?

Sripts.js:

```
function sendAnswers() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'result',
        data: {
            res_list: resultList()
        },
        success: function () {
        }
    })
    location.href = 'result'
}

function resultList() {
    let allAnswersList = [];
    allAnswersList = getCheckedCheckBoxes().concat(getSequence())
    return allAnswersList
}
```

Views.py:

```
def result(request):
    user_answers_list = request.POST.getlist('res_list[]')
    context = {'res_lst': user_answers_list }
    return render(request, 'main/result.html', context)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('registration/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('registration', views.registration, name='registration'),
    path('test', views.test, name='test'),
    path('result', views.result, name='result')
]
```

result.html:

```
 <div class="alert alert-warning mt-2" id="mainArea">
    {% for question in testing %}
        <div class="alert alert-secondary mt-2" id="questionArea{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
            <form method="post" id='testForm' data-url="{% url 'test' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <table>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>{{ forloop.counter }}. {{ question.1 }}</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
                {% if question.4 %}
                    {% for images in img %}
                        {% if images.picture == question.4 %}
                            <img src="{{ images.picture.url }}" class="mainImg" alt=""><br>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
                {% if question.0 == '1' %}
                    {% for el in question.2 %}
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="getCheckedCheckBoxes()"
                                   name="{{ question.1 }}"
                                   value="{{ el }}" id="{{ question.1 }}"/> {{ el }}
                        </label><br>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% else %}
                    <label>
                        {% for num in question.2 %}
                            <h6>{{ forloop.counter }}. </h6>
                            <select id="myselect" class="myselect" name="myselect" onchange="getSequence()">
                                <option disabled selected></option>
                                {% for el in question.2 %}
                                    <option value="{{ el }}" id="{{ question.1 }}{{ forloop.counter0 }}"
                                            label="{{ el }}">
                                    </option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select><br>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </label>
                {% endif %}
            </form>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="button" value="snd" id="sendAnsButton" onclick="sendAnswers()" class="button">Завершить тест</button>
</div>
```

Console:

```
[18/Sep/2020 16:36:33] "POST /result HTTP/1.1" 200 33229
[18/Sep/2020 16:36:33] "GET /result HTTP/1.1" 200 33229
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `result` view to accept only POST requests.

You can make either use [`@require_GET`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_GET)

```py
@require_GET
def result(request):
    ...
```

or just add an `if` statement in your `result`:

```
def result(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # your code
```

also you can return an error for bad requests:

```
def result(request):
    if request.method != "GET":
        return HttpResponseBadRequest("Expecting GET request")
```